# Problem with i2c communication between arduino and raspberrypi

Tags: python, i2c, arduino

I have connected Rpi with Arduino using i2c communication. Pin Configuration: Rpi ---- Arduino Mega SDA SDA SCL SCL GND GND

I also have an encoder attached to Rpi. Encoder `------ Rpi 5V 5V Gnd Gnd Output A Gpio 17 (BCM layout) Output B Gpio 18 (BCM Layout)

Code is working perfectly fine, however after sometime, I am getting an error: 121, Remote I/O Error.

Also, before the error (before starting the communication), on executing i2cdetect -y 1, I see only one slave address (20) same address as my Pi.

However, after the error, on executing i2cdetect -y 1, I get 2 addresses, even tho only Arduino is connected.

```
Output for before communication:
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f  
00           --  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10   -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20   20 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30   -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40   -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50   -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60   -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70   -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

```
Output after error, on executing i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f  
00           03  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10   -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20   20 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30   -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40   -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50   -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60   -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70   -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

```py
Python:
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import serial
import os
import smbus
#import time
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
time.sleep(1)
address = 0x20


GPIO.setmode (GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(True)

i=0
pin_A = 17
pin_B = 18

######################################################################
def writeNumber(value):
    bus.write_byte(address, value)
    return -1

def readNumber():
    number = bus.read_byte(address)

    return number
###################################################################
Encoder_Count = 0
A_Pos2=0
GPIO.setup (pin_A, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup (pin_B, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)#Button to GPIO23
A_Pos = 0
A_Last = "00"
STATE = {"0001":1,"0010":-1,"0100":-1,"0111":1,"1000":1,"1011":-1, "1101":-1, "1110":1}     

def Encoder1(channel1):
    global Encoder_Count,A_Pos,A_Last,STATE
    now = str(GPIO.input(17)) + str(GPIO.input(18))
    key = A_Last + now
    if key in STATE:
            direction = STATE[key]
            A_Last = now
            A_Pos +=direction


GPIO.add_event_detect (pin_A, GPIO.BOTH, callback=Encoder1)  
GPIO.add_event_detect (pin_B, GPIO.BOTH, callback=Encoder1)
i=0
#while(i<10):
while(1):
    var = 100
        button_state = GPIO.input(23)
   # ser.write(b'1')
        A_Pos2= A_Pos/(1600)
        time.sleep(0.01)
    print A_Pos2
    writeNumber(A_Pos2)
        if (A_Pos2 ==-6):
        #writeNumber(7)

        A_Pos = A_Pos % 6
        time.sleep(0.01)
    if (A_Pos2 ==6):

        #writeNumber(A_Pos2)
        #A_Pos=0
        A_Pos = A_Pos % 6
        time.sleep(0.01)

    #else:


        if button_state == False:
            # GPIO.output(24, True)
            os.system("sudo shutdown now -h")


GPIO.cleanup()
```

```
Arduino
Arduino:
#include <Wire.h>
#define SLAVE_ADDRESS 0x20
int number = 0;
void setup()
{

    Wire.begin(SLAVE_ADDRESS);
  Wire.onReceive(receiveData);

  delay(2000);

}

void loop()
{
if (number == 10)
{
// do something
}

// callback for wire communication:
void receiveData(int byteCount) {

  if (Wire.available()) {
     digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
    number = Wire.read();

    Serial.println (number);
    delay(100);

}
```

Comment: That sounds like a wiring problem.  Are all the wires soldered or decent quality dupont connectors?  A photo or photos clearly showing the connections between Pi and Arduino will be helpful.

Comment: While it may often work and probably is not a huge risk (potential physical damage to the Pi), connecting the Pi's 3.3V I2C bus to the Mega's 5V I2C is not a great idea.  You need a level shifter in between them.

Comment: @Vaibhav Thacker, Questions: (1) Why are you not using the Rpi standard I2C GPIO pins 2,3? (2) What is the "encoder" you are referring? Does this encoder converts Mega's 5V I2C pins signals to 3V3 and also does something else, like pretending to be a slave with address 0x20?

Comment: @Vaibhav Thacker, suggest the following tests, if your have Rpi4B and buster: (1) Lower I2C speed from 100kHz to 10kHz, (2) Set up four I2C channels and swap compare and contrast, (3) Other tricks as suggested in my answer below.

Comment: @goldilocks We do have i2c level shifter, still getting this error

Comment: @tlfong01, I am using Raspberrypi 3  I2C pins(Pin 3 and 5, two pins below 3.3V). The encoders are connected to the motors to calculate the speed, It is processed by Rpi and sends the processed values to Arduino.

Comment: @tlfong01, I am using Rpi 3 b+, what is the preferred clock speed?

Comment: *"We do have i2c level shifter"* -> You should really try to be thorough in presenting your information, because not everyone is going to bother to ask for relevant details if you don't bother to provide them.

Comment: @Vaibhav Thacker, Well, if you are using Rpi3B, then bad luck, because it uses a flat speed of 100kHz.  For Rpi4B, you can start with 10kHz, and go up if higher speed improves performance.  Or you can forget I2C and use SPI instead, Rpi3B SPI can set speed to as low as 10kHz.

Comment: @Vaibhav Thacker, if i2cdetect detects more addresses than it should, that means the line is noisy, and if many many more random addresses, that means very noisy, or very crazy.  You can find my listed i2c module a ping function and also a "read-wait-write-register" function to check you can read back what is written.  If it to often fails or always fails, then it means I2C device crashes and need to reset.

Comment: @Vaibhav Thacker, If you are playing with motor, and PWM, H bridges etc, then there might be back EMF or EMI that might crash the system.  Usually you use optical isolator to prevent that.  It is also useful to use separate power supplies and also separate power grounds from signal ground.

Comment: @tlfong01, my code worked upon changing the i2c clock from default to 10k. It works even with Rpi 3 apparently.  Thank you so much for the help

Comment: @Vaibhav Thacker, Ah, there might be a problem with your 10kHz.  As I once tested, even if you modify your /bootconfig.txt to set I2C to a different frequency, actually Rpi3B stretch ignores your statement and keep using 100kHz.  You may like to confirm by displaying the waveform using a scope.  BTW, I am also playing with motors with encoders.  You might like to read the following post to know more details. Perhaps later I can try to check the noise of the motor, to see if it crashes the I2C. Bed time.  See you. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=234304&start=25#p1441581

Answer (score 0):

***Question***

> Error 121, Remote I/O Error

***Answer***

The above error means many things, including the following:

> 1. Forgot to connect the I2C connectors.
> 2. Device gets crazy.

For 2, I usually reset the device.  For example MCP23017 has a reset pin which I connect to a manual reset button 10k pull up to Vcc, which can reset by hand or by Rpi. (In your case, reset Arduino, or Rpi, or both, or restart their I2C programs.)

If the device has no reset pin, then I can manual or software reset the power to the device (LM2596, LM2941, which has power reset pins, or can be a current/power switch).

To prevent I2C IO errors, there are many tricks, including the following:

> 1. Use short wires, less than 30cm if possible.
> 2. Twist the wires, or use CAT5 (already twisted pairs).
> 3. Lower the I2C clock speed.  Rpi3 has a bug and only do a flat rate of 100kHz.  For Rpi4B, you set  I2C speed down to as low as 10kHz. 
>      You will find all kinds of line noise, switching noise/ringing
>      reduced, and Error 121 less frequent.
> 4. Convert Rpi 3V3 I2C signals to 5V.  5V circuits usually has a higher tolerance to noise and can therefore go higher speed.  I
>      usually use TXS010x (TXB0x0x is better).
> 5. Separate power supplies for Rpi and devices, separate grounding wires etc, ...
> 6. Use I2C buffers and expanders (expensive, only for industrial applications)
> 7. Remove onboard's 4k7/10k pull down, because Rpi I2C pins already use 1k7 pullups, which is strong enough.
> 8. Rpi4B has 4 I2C channels, I usually swap channels 1, 3, 4, 5 to compare and contrast (Appendix A).
> 9. Use the SPI version to compare, if there is one.  For example, I got fed up with I2C MCP23017, I switch to SPI MCP23S17.  Many devices
>      have I2C and SPI pins on the same chip, and that is handy.
> 10. More tricks I forgot, ... :)

***References***

(1) [I2C Long Cables Dsicussion](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=77158&start=325#p1351758)

(2) [I2C References - NXP, TI](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=77158&start=325#p1352201)

(3) [TSX010x References - TI](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=77158&start=325#p1352292)

(4) [I2C Long Cable References - NXP](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=77158&start=325#p1352373)

(5) [I2C Switch/Expander References - TI](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=77158&start=300#p1350946)

(6) [I2C Buses Learning Notes - TI](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=77158&start=300#p1351223)

(7) [I2C and SMBus Learning Notes - Linux](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=77158&start=300#p1351268)

(8) [MCP23017 x 8 on the same I2C Bus](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=77158&start=375#p1362527)

***Appendices***

(A) *Testing Rpi4B buster 4 I2C Channels*

> I2c Bus Setup Notes
>
> pi@raspberrypi:~ $ date Wed 28 Aug 2019 03:26:24 PM HKT
>
> pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
>
> Linux raspberrypi 4.19.58-v7l+ #1245 SMP Fri Jul 12 17:31:45 BST 2019 armv7l
>
> pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo nano /boot/config.txt
>
> dtoverlay=i2c1,pins_2_3  (board pins 3, 5)
>
> dtoverlay=i2c3,pins_4_5  (board pins 7, 29)
>
> dtoverlay=i2c4,pins_6_7  (board pins 31, 26)
>
> dtoverlay=i2c5,pins_12_13 (board pins 32, 33)
>
> dtoverlay=i2c6,pins_22_23 (board pins 15, 16)
>
> pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls /dev/i2c*
>
> ***/dev/i2c-1  /dev/i2c-3  /dev/i2c-4  /dev/i2c-5  /dev/i2c-6***

```
# fi2c62.py  tlfong01 2019aug28hkt1433

from time          import sleep
import             smbus
import             fprint53    as fprint
import             ftime53     as ftime

# I2c Bus Setup Notes
# pi@raspberrypi:~ $ date Wed 28 Aug 2019 03:26:24 PM HKT
# pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
# Linux raspberrypi 4.19.58-v7l+ #1245 SMP Fri Jul 12 17:31:45 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
# pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo nano /boot/config.txt
# dtoverlay=i2c1,pins_2_3  (board pins 3, 5)
# dtoverlay=i2c3,pins_4_5  (board pins 7, 29)
# dtoverlay=i2c4,pins_6_7  (board pins 31, 26)
# dtoverlay=i2c5,pins_12_13 (board pins 32, 33)
# dtoverlay=i2c6,pins_22_23 (board pins 15, 16)
# pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls /dev/i2c*
# /dev/i2c-1  /dev/i2c-3  /dev/i2c-4  /dev/i2c-5  /dev/i2c-6

# ********************************************************************************
# ********************************************************************************

# *** I2c Bus Config ***

i2cBus1 = smbus.SMBus(1) 
i2cBus3 = smbus.SMBus(3)
i2cBus4 = smbus.SMBus(4)
i2cBus5 = smbus.SMBus(5)

i2cBusDict = {'I2cBus1': i2cBus1,
              'I2cBus3': i2cBus3,
              'I2cBus4': i2cBus4,
              'I2cBus5': i2cBus5,
             }

# *** Pca9685 I2c Slave Device Congif ***

pca9685DevAddrDict = {
                'Dev0': 0x40,
                'Dev1': 0x41,
                'Dev2': 0x42,
                'Dev3': 0x43,
                'Dev4': 0x44,
                'Dev5': 0x45,
                'Dev6': 0x46,
                'Dev7': 0x47,
              }

pca9685RegAddrDict = { 'Mode1': 0x00,
                       'Mode2': 0x01,
                     }

pca9685DataByteDict = {
                       'Mode1Reset': 0x11,

    }

# ********************************************************************************
# ********************************************************************************

# *** Read Write Print Device/Register Functions ***

def writeDevTwoBytes(i2cBus, devAddr, writeByte1, writeByte2):
    i2cBus.write_byte_data(devAddr, writeByte1, writeByte2)
    return

def writeRegOneByte(i2cBus, devAddrDict, devName, regAddrDict, regName, writeByte):
    devAddr = devAddrDict[devName]
    regAddr = regAddrDict[regName]
    writeDevTwoBytes(i2cBus, devAddr, regAddr, writeByte)
    return

def readDevOneByte(i2cBus, devAddr, readByteAddr):
    readByte = i2cBus.read_byte_data(devAddr, readByteAddr)
    return readByte

def readRegOneByte(i2cBus, devAddrDict, devName, regAddrDict, regName):
    devAddr = devAddrDict[devName]
    regAddr = regAddrDict[regName]
    readByte = i2cBus.read_byte_data(devAddr, regAddr)
    return readByte

def printRegOneByte(i2cBus, devAddrDict, devName, regAddrDict, regName):
    readByte = readRegOneByte(i2cBusName, devAddrDict, devName, regAddrDict, regName)
    print(printTitle, hex(readByte))
    return

# *** Main Test Function ***

def testWriteReadPca9685Bus1Dev0RegMode1():     
    fprint.printBeginExecFunction()

    i2cBusName = 'I2cBus1'
    devName    = 'Dev0'
    regName    = 'Mode1'

    #i2cBus      = fi2c.i2cBusDict[i2cBusName]
    i2cBus      = i2cBusDict[i2cBusName]
    devAddrDict = pca9685DevAddrDict
    regAddrDict = pca9685RegAddrDict  

    writeByte = 0x77

    writeRegOneByte(i2cBus, devAddrDict, devName, regAddrDict, regName, writeByte)
    readByte = readRegOneByte(i2cBus, devAddrDict, devName, regAddrDict, regName) 

    if readByte == writeByte:
        resultsString = 'Good'
    else:
        resultsString = 'Bad'

    devAddr = devAddrDict[devName]

    fprint.printTitleOneByteNum('PCA9685 I2C Address',             fprint.indentFormat640, devAddr)
    fprint.printTitleOneByteNum('PCA9685 MODE1 Register Written',  fprint.indentFormat640, writeByte) 
    fprint.printTitleOneByteNum('PCA9685 MODE1 Register Read',     fprint.indentFormat640, readByte)    
    fprint.printTitleString('Write/Read Results',                  fprint.indentFormat640, resultsString)

    fprint.printEndExecFunction()
    return

def testPingPca9685Bus1Dev0RegMode1():     
    fprint.printBeginExecFunction()

    i2cBusName = 'I2cBus1'
    devName    = 'Dev0'
    regName    = 'Mode1'

    #i2cBus      = fi2c.i2cBusDict[i2cBusName]
    i2cBus      = i2cBusDict[i2cBusName]
    devAddrDict = pca9685DevAddrDict
    regAddrDict = pca9685RegAddrDict

    devAddr = devAddrDict[devName]

    readByte = readRegOneByte(i2cBus, devAddrDict, devName, regAddrDict, regName)    

    compareByte = pca9685DataByteDict['Mode1Reset'] 

    if readByte == compareByte:
        resultsString = 'Good'
    else:
        resultsString = 'Bad'

    fprint.printTitleString('PCA9685 I2C Address',             fprint.indentFormat640, hex(devAddr))
    fprint.printTitleString('PCA9685 MODE1 Register Written',  fprint.indentFormat640, hex(compareByte)) 
    fprint.printTitleString('PCA9685 MODE1 Register Read',     fprint.indentFormat640, hex(readByte))    
    fprint.printTitleString('Ping Results',                    fprint.indentFormat640, resultsString)

    fprint.printEndExecFunction()
    return

# ********************************************************************************
# ********************************************************************************

# *** Main Tests ***

def mainTests():
    #ftime.testPrintDateTime()
    testPingPca9685Bus1Dev0RegMode1()
    testWriteReadPca9685Bus1Dev0RegMode1()
    return

# ********************************************************************************
# ********************************************************************************

# *** Init/Main Functions ***

# *** Init Function ***

def init():
    pass
    return

#*** Main Function ***

def main():
    init()
    mainTests()    
    return

# ********************************************************************************
# ********************************************************************************

# *** Main ***

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

# *** End of Program ***

# ********************************************************************************
# ********************************************************************************
```

*.END*